# Noflo: Steps to run inside browser when frontend is Angular 4 CLI

Tags: angular, webpack, gruntjs, noflo

I am trying to run noflo in browser, with a twist that it will be an Angular App. Noflo documentation mentions following:

> NoFlo projects can also run in web browsers. You can use the webpack tool create a browser-runnable build of a NoFlo project.
>
> In nutshell, making a browser build of a NoFlo project involves the following steps:
>
> Find all installed browser-compatible components using the fbp-manifest tool
>
> Generate a custom NoFlo component loader that requires all the component files and registers them for NoFlo to load
>
> Configure and run webpack with the application entry point, replacing NoFlo’s standard component loader with the generated custom one
>
> To automate these steps we have grunt-noflo-browser, a plugin for the Grunt task runner that we use for build automation.

I have doubts regarding shortest and least painful path to take for this task:

Option 1:

> I am using Angular CLI. Webpack comes integrated with angular cli which can be moved to webpack based configuration by using "ng eject" command, and then I can use Grunt task runner to set it up. I have never before used Grunt. I have no idea how will it work out. Another headache that thereafter I will have to manage webpack configurations going further into development.

Option 2:

> Same as above but do everything manually. Removes the headache of going Grunt path. Creates new questions and complexities about how to use fbp-manifest tool and how to generate custom NoFlo Component loader. Also maintaining webpack configurations is an added task going further into development.

Option 3:

> If any other path exists specific to Angular CLI

I will be integrating Noflo and customizing it heavily for my application. My nodes will be new as well as there will be no server running and I will have my own system of pushing IP. The idea is to integrate Noflo and Noflo UI, reuse as much as possible and develop the rest.

I will appreciate any advice regarding this.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is primarily that we need to generate a statically configured NoFlo component loader for browsers, since they can't discover available components from the file system.

This functionality used to be strongly coupled with the grunt-noflo-browser module.

However, as of today, it should be possible to build NoFlo as part of any existing WebPack setup using the [noflo-component-loader](https://github.com/noflo/noflo-component-loader) WebPack plugin. Add something like the following to your WebPack `module.rules`:

```
{
  // Replace NoFlo's dynamic loader with a generated one
  test: /noflo\/lib\/loader\/register.js$/,
  use: [
    {
      loader: 'noflo-component-loader',
      options: {
        // Only include components used by this graph
        // Set to NULL if you want all installed components
        graph: 'myproject/GraphName',
        // Whether to include the original component sources
        // in the build
        debug: false,
      },
    },
  ],
},
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It is very helpful.